# How to pop out a window in react js functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web-frontend, react-functional-component

On click of a button, new window should open(url should be visible).

It should not open in new tab/as a modal/as a pop-up.

It should open as a pop-out in react functional components.

I tried **window.open** but it is opening in new tab and not as pop-out window.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] showing the issue

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As the sites are restricted in my company, I don't have access and I have asked from my mobile. Else I would have provided the code. Could you please provide sample code snippet ? Thanks a ton

Comment: _"Could you please provide sample code snippet?"_ - this is what I'm asking you to do. We can't see the code you're struggling with.